# NiceMatrices in Subequations-Environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, subequations, nicematrix

I have not the minimal idea about create this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
NiceMatrix_1 \label{NiceMatrix_1}\\
NiceMatrix_2 \label{NiceMatrix_2}\\
\vdots \\
NiceMatrix_n \label{NiceMatrix_n}\\
\end{subequations}

While: \[
NiceMatrix_1 = \begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=8.5mm,cell-space-limits=2pt,hvlines]
\diagbox{\small A_i} {\small A^j} 
& A^1 & A^2 & A^3 \\
A_1 & \Block{3-3}{}
      1 & 2 & 3 \\
A_2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
A_3 & 7 & 8 & 9 
\CodeAfter
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \begin{scope} [dashed]
      \draw ([xshift=3mm]3-|2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]3-|5) ;
      \draw ([xshift=3mm]4-|2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]4-|5) ;
      \draw (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ;
      \draw (2-|4) -- (5-|4) ;
    \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{NiceMatrix}
\]

\[NiceMatrix_2 = ... \]
\[\vdots \]
\[NiceMatrix_n = ... \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Apart from not being compilable due to the `_` inside of the `subequations` environment, what exactly is the issue here? What kind of output do you expect?

Comment: My problem is: I'd like to create a subequations with nicematrices, but it's impossible, because there is a Fatal NiceMatrix Package Error. Hence I'd like to ask you how could I solve my problem. Thank you so much

Comment: You should post as the minimal (non)-working example (MWE) which causes this fatal error from `nicematrix`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem using environments of `nicematrix` (such as `{NiceMatrix}`) in a `{align}` itself in a `{subequations}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}\label{eq:all}
\NiceMatrixOptions{columns-width=8.5mm,cell-space-limits=2pt,hvlines}
\begin{align}
\label{NiceMatrix_1}
M_1 & = 
        \begin{NiceMatrix}
            \diagbox{A_i}{A^j} 
            & A^1 & A^2 & A^3 \\
            A_1 & \Block{3-3}{}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            A_2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
            A_3 & 7 & 8 & 9 
            \CodeAfter
            \begin{tikzpicture} 
                \begin{scope} [dashed]
                    \draw ([xshift=3mm]3-|2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]3-|5) ;
                    \draw ([xshift=3mm]4-|2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]4-|5) ;
                    \draw (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ;
                    \draw (2-|4) -- (5-|4) ;
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{NiceMatrix} \\
\label{NiceMatrix_2}
M_2 & = 
        \begin{NiceMatrix}
                1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{NiceMatrix} \\
\label{NiceMatrix_3}
M_3 & = 
        \begin{NiceMatrix}
                4 & 5 & 6 \\                                    
        \end{NiceMatrix} 
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

 See \eqref{eq:all}: \eqref{NiceMatrix_1}, \eqref{NiceMatrix_2} and \eqref{NiceMatrix_3}. 

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 2):

This code produces the desired result.

[image: c]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=1.5cm,bottom=1.5cm,left=2cm,right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{stix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[customcolors,shade]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,backgrounds}

\begin{document}
    
    \newcommand{\NiceMatrixi}{% 
        \begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=8.5mm,cell-space-limits=2pt,hvlines]
            \diagbox{A_i} {\A^j} 
            & A^1 & A^2 & A^3 \\
            A_1 & \Block{3-3}{}
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            A_2 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
            A_3 & 7 & 8 & 9 
            \CodeAfter
            \begin{tikzpicture} 
                \begin{scope} [dashed]
                    \draw ([xshift=3mm]3-|2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]3-|5) ;
                    \draw ([xshift=3mm]4-|2) -- ([xshift=-3mm]4-|5) ;
                    \draw (2-|3) -- (5-|3) ;
                    \draw (2-|4) -- (5-|4) ;
                \end{scope}
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{NiceMatrix}
        }
    
        \newcommand{\NiceMatrixii}{%
        \begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=8.5mm,cell-space-limits=2pt,hvlines]
                1 & 2 & 3 \\
        \end{NiceMatrix}
    }

        \newcommand{\NiceMatrixiii}{%
         \begin{NiceMatrix}[columns-width=8.5mm,cell-space-limits=2pt,hvlines]
                4 & 5 & 6 \\                                    
        \end{NiceMatrix}
}
    

 \begin{subequations}\label{eq:all}
    \begin{align}
        \label{NiceMatrix_1}
        NiceMatrix_1 &= \NiceMatrixi \\
        \label{NiceMatrix_2}
        NiceMatrix_2 &= \NiceMatrixii \\
        \label{NiceMatrix_3}
        NiceMatrix_3 &= \NiceMatrixiii 
    \end{align}
 \end{subequations}

 
 While:
 
 \[NiceMatrix_1=\NiceMatrixi\]   
 \[NiceMatrix_2=\NiceMatrixii\]
 \[\vdots \]
 \[NiceMatrix_3=\NiceMatrixiii\]     
 
 See \eqref{eq:all}: \eqref{NiceMatrix_1}, \eqref{NiceMatrix_2} and \eqref{NiceMatrix_3}. 
 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Your answer is what I desired! Thanks again